# passing in a rotated bitmap to process

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I have a bitmap that I rotate and I would like to pass in the rotated bitmap to be processed but it seems like from my code it is passing in the original bitmap and not the rotated one.

Any idea to how I could adjust this?

```
 using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
 {
   try
   {   
     RectangleF cloneRect = new RectangleF(0,0, fullImg.Width,fullImg.Height);
     PixelFormat format = fullImg.PixelFormat;

     Bitmap result = fullImg.Clone(cloneRect, format);
     result.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

     string QRinfo = Process(result);
     MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know about "Process", but using your code I've done this instead: pictureBox2.Image = result; and it works flawlessly.

Do you mean System.Diagnostics.Process? That's a class not a method.

Comment: @Picacodigos sorry - process is another method that i pass in the rotated image to get out of it the qr code number. So it is a method that i have named process.